# Converting a string with two pairs of digit strings into a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that contains a decimal value in "ab.xy" (for example "32.15"). I need to convert this to a decimal number like ab.xy (32.15).

Should I do

```
     float (number_string)
```

or should i do

```
     decimal.Decimal(number_string)
```

We don't want the integrity of the decimal number represented in the string to be changed. Meaning we want the number represented in the string to be converted exactly as is to decimal number. According to blog [Decimal vs float in Python](https://blog.tecladocode.com/decimal-vs-float-in-python/), using `decimal.Decimal` is better than `float`. Can you please weigh in?

Comment: You should use `decimal.Decimal` or `fraction.Fraction` if you don't want to have errors related to the floating-point representation. Since you are starting off with a string representation of a decimal number, `decimal.Decimal` seems to be the best choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floats cannot be represented exactly as they are. I would use decimal or fraction.

Alternatively convert the strings to integers, and only at the last possible stage revert back to two decimals. This is my preferred option if I have to do calculations and comparisons using the numbers.

Comment: Using integers is a good trick when you know that there are always two decimal places - you can simply store `value * 100`. I've seen that used for calculations with money. On the other hand, using `decimal` is more explicit. And fractions are great for maintaining precision even after dividing two values.

Comment: If you have large datasets integers are more efficient. Although not completely sure, I think the decimal implementation is actually just using fractions that are basically just 2 intergers eg. Fraction(10, 100) = 0.1